# Не группируются селекторы при наследовании

Tags: css

Хотел всем элементам в DIV class="bs2" добавить красную рамку вокруг, написал такое:

```
.bs2 P, DIV {border: 1px solid red;}
```

После долгих мучений выяснилось, что работает только так:

```
.bs2 P {border: 1px solid red;}

.bs2 DIV {border: 1px solid red;}
```

Через запятую не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что

```
.bs2 p,
.bs2 div {border: 1px solid red;}
```

Comment: @dvserzhantov, не раскидывайтесь кармой, слева от ответа есть галочка) ("принять ответ"). Не за что)